# Connect to WinForm server using SignalR?

Tags: java, android, signalr, signalr.client

I have downloaded the official example of `SignalR` and it works fine when I try to connect from WinFormsClient to  WinFormsServer. Everything just fine...

I downloaded the SignalR for android and tried to make a connection using the code below, but no success what so ever...I only get `SocketTimeoutException`. Here is my code, maybe someone can help me out!

I am trying this on a real device. Both PC and device are on same wifi network.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
    String host = "http://192.168.0.11:8080/signalr";
    HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(host);
    HubProxy proxy = connection.createHubProxy("MyHub");

    SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start();
    try {
        awaitConnection.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    proxy.invoke("Send", new String[]{"Hahahahahhahaha", "shit shit shit!"});
    proxy.on("AddMessage", new SubscriptionHandler2<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void run(String p1, String p2) {
            Log.d("result := ", p1 + " ---- " + p2);
        }
    }, String.class, String.class); }
});
```

Comment: Using a device or emulator?

Comment: @greenapps a device of course. I had to add that to question.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain why you don't have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ?

Comment: @greenapps Well!!! Thats a good point that I didnt think of...does it mean there is no network activity at all?

Comment: `String host = "http://192.168.0.11:8080/signalr";`. You call that `host` where in fact it is an url. The host is 192.168.0.11.  Now what does new HubConnection expect? A host or an url?

Comment: No that means that you have to put your network code in an AsyncTask or thread.

Comment: @greenapps the winformclient example uses that exact url to connect to winformserver...so I thought it should be the same for android as well. Regarding the networkOnMain, I guess SignalR has its own threads

Comment: Android is different. It is not about the url but about the main thread. Well do you have a NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: @greenapps no, the only exception I faced is SocketTimeoutException

Comment: I tried `192.168.0.11:8080` as url also ...same thing

Comment: You have a firewall? Please switch it off for a test. Before you do that use that url in a browser on your device.

Comment: @greenapps I can make connection between phone and app using telnet and Socket so I guess its not a firewall/router problem. When I put in phone's browser192.168.0.11:8080 with or withour /signalr nothing happens :(

Comment: @greenapps YES IT WAS a firewall problem :P you can write the answer so I accept :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your firewall may block the connection.